# How can i ignore the warning when i deleted a piece manually from my apostrophe-project?

Tags: content-management-system, apostrophe-cms, headless-cms

I have deleted a piece from my apostrophe project manually. now when i run the project it is shows as  a warning that:
It looks like you may have made a mistake in your code:

The module banners does not extend anything and does not have a
`beforeConstruct`, `construct` or `afterConstruct` function. This usually means that you:

1. Forgot to `extend` another module

The module banners does not extend anything and does not have a
`beforeConstruct`, `construct` or `afterConstruct` function. This usually means that you:

1. Forgot to `extend` another module
2. Configured a module that comes from npm without npm installing it
3. Simply haven't written your `index.js` yet

If you really want a module with no code, set the `ignoreNoCodeWarning` option
to `true` for this module.

What should i do to ignore this warning?

Comment: I don't fully understand. You have a piece module called `banners`. You had added some "banner" pieces in the UI, then you deleted them directly through the MongoDB CLI? Or did you delete the piece type from your project?

Comment: From the project..But Now the issue is resolved..Thanks for your kind attention